# Buttons to fit screen and buttons should be at bottom when not fit screen

Tags: android, kotlin

I am printing buttons programmatically and have set the orientation to horizontal as you can see in the id `@+id/linearLayout`, which is where the buttons print programmatically.

**activity_mail.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/MainActivity"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

...

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


</LinearLayout>
```

The code I am using to print the buttons programmatically is as follows:

**MainActivity.kt**

```
private fun createAndAddView()
{
    val array: Array<Int> = concat.toTypedArray()
    //val textView = TextView(this)
    //val btn = Button(this)

    val params = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200,
          LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

    //params.gravity = RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT;

    //btn.text = array.first().toString()
    for (i in array) {
        val btn = Button(this)
        //btn.width = 5
        //btn.height = 5
        btn.text = i.toString()
        btn.layoutParams = params
        //btn.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT
        linearLayout.addView(btn)
    }
}
```

The problem that I have is that when buttons are printed, the buttons goes off the screen, I expect the buttons to print under the buttons. How could I make the buttons print under the buttons to fit screen only?

[image: The button should have printed below]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use [ConstraintLayout Flow](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/helper/widget/Flow), but you have to replace the `LinearLayout` with `ConstraintLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.helper.widget.Flow
            android:id="@+id/flow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:flow_horizontalGap="8dp"
            app:flow_maxElementsWrap="5"
            app:flow_verticalGap="8dp"
            app:flow_verticalStyle="packed"
            app:flow_wrapMode="aligned" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

You can get rid of the `ScrollView` if you are sure that the no. of buttons is limited and can't exceed the screen height.

And add the views programmatically with:

```
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT

private fun createAndAddView() {
    val root = findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.root)
    val size = 14 // No. of buttons needed
    val array = IntArray(size)
    for (i in 0 until size) {
        array[i] = i + 1
        val button = Button(this).apply {
            layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(0, WRAP_CONTENT)
            id = i + 1
            text = "${i + 1}"
        }
        root.addView(button)
    }
    val flow = findViewById<Flow>(R.id.flow)
    flow.referencedIds = array
}
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like it is close to working, but I think the way I have the code setup is making it look messed up.

Comment: I have project here, so you can look at it: https://github.com/alextech1/RandomGenerator

Comment: not sure if you have time, would like feedback on this issue, here is pic: https://imgur.com/a/ZAKKHhx

Comment: @AlejandroH .. I think the problem that the button text is set to the array[i]+1 .. Have a look [here](https://pastebin.com/4JcvcTTN) pls; also changed the ids of the flow by using the indices as they have to be unique numbers just in case the generated numbers duplicate.

Comment: when this method `root.addView(button)` runs, the buttons stack on each other, why is that?

Comment: What do you mean by `stack on each other`? on one stack? they already shown on multiple stacks/columns on the width of the screen

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/IHalhdI , I will try to figure it out. It is stacking on top of each other as it makes buttons on `root.addView(button)`. I had tried to do it on a new xml and it happens to do the same.

Comment: Also I did forget to change code to `flow.referencedIds = (1 .. array.size).toList().toIntArray()` . however it still  stacks. I think I need to remove `root.addView(button)` ?

Comment: sorry I also forgot to change `i` to `index`. after that code is working fine. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FlexboxLayoutManager` for that.

**Steps:**

**1. Create a Recyclerview in your Xml**

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvButtons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="4dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**2. Create Recyclerview adapter and initialize it with values**

```
inner class ButtonsAdapter(private val buttonsList: IntArray) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<ButtonsAdapter.VH>() {

        inner class VH(val binding: ItemButtonBinding) :
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        }

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): VH {
            return VH(ItemButtonBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false))
        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return buttonsList.size
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: VH, position: Int) {
            holder.binding.btn.text = buttonsList[holder.bindingAdapterPosition].toString()
        }
    }
```

**3. Set adapter to the recyclerview with `FlexboxLayoutManager`**

```
private val array: IntArray = intArrayOf(15, 20, 54, 10, 41, 35, 3, 50, 64, 80, 99, 13)
rvButtons.adapter = ButtonsAdapter(array)
val lm = FlexboxLayoutManager(this, FlexDirection.ROW)
lm.flexWrap = FlexWrap.WRAP
rvButtons.layoutManager = lm
val paddingDecoration = FlexboxItemDecoration(this)
        paddingDecoration.setDrawable(
        ContextCompat.getDrawable(
        this,
        R.drawable.flexbox_divider
        )
    )
rvButtons.addItemDecoration(paddingDecoration)
rvButtons.adapter = ButtonsAdapter(array)
```

**flexbox_divider.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <size android:width="2dp" />
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
</shape>
```

Here is what you get after following these steps.

[image: Final output]

Comment: Hello, what is `ItemButtonsBinding`? It says "Unresolved reference: ItemButtonBinding".

Comment: @AlejandroH It's just `viewBinding` method for accessing the views directly in the activity or fragments, so that you don't need to do `findViewById()`. You can go with traditional `findViewById()` if you don't prefer the viewBinding. Just inflate the layout with the simple way and then bind the ids in viewholder class.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `recyclerview` just use `GridLayoutManager` if you want specific number of buttons to be shown on screen.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the **linearLayout's** width to **wrap_content**. This will tell the **linearLayout** to only take up as much width as it needs. The buttons will then be able to fit under each other without overlapping.

You can try out below code :

```
private fun createAndAddbtnView()
{
    val array: Array<Int> = concat.toTypedArray()
    //val textView = TextView(this)
    //val btn = Button(this)

    val params = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
          LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

    //params.gravity = RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT;

    //btn.text = array.first().toString()
    for (i in array) {
        val mbtn = Button(this)
        //btn.width = 5
        //btn.height = 5
        mbtn .text = i.toString()
        mbtn .layoutParams = params
        //btn.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT
        linearLayout.addView(mbtn)
    }

    linearLayout.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
          LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    linearLayout.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM
}
```

This code will set the linearLayout's width to wrap_content and its gravity to bottom. This will ensure that the buttons fit under each other and do not go off the screen.